# Combinations from database c# sql

Tags: c#, mysql, combinations, permutation

I am working in c#.I have data in the database as mentioned below

ID        ParentID
1                  1
2                  1
3                  2
4                  2
5                  2
6                  3
7                  3
8                  3

i want to get all the combinations of Id based on Parent Id as a group or something. That is

1,3,6
1,3,7
1,3,8

1,4,6
1,4,7
1,4,8

1,5,6
1,5,7
1,5,8

2,3,6
2,3,7
2,3,8

etc...

How can i get all the combinations when my parentId are dynamic. It can be 1,2,3... until 50 also.

Comment: You have hugely underestimated the number of possible combinations involved. If you have 50 elements there are trillions and trillions of different ways in which you can combine them.

Comment: @e4c5 yes. now i understand the complications...